# d3js data object has duplicate data in its children and values properties if using nest()?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am palying with d3js these days, trying to make sense here:

Initially, I have a json data file actually with this content:

`[{name:one, role:admin, accessLevel:0},{name:two, role:user,accessLevel:1},{name:three,role:guest,accessLevel:2}]`

So in order to make this data valid, I wrapped the orginal data with a root. Also in my design, I want the data is sorted with 'accessLevel' firstly, then 'role'

```
var treeData = {}
d3.json(url,function(source){


var sortedTree = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.accessLevel })
        .key(function(d) { return d.role})
        .entries(source)
treeData['root'] = sortedTree
})

// I now have a json data source like:
// {root : [{...},{...},{...}]
// and it was sorted off step 2
```

I am planing to make a tree dendrogram, and I explicitly defined the children of my data:

```
 var tree = d3.layout.tree()
        .children(function(d) { return d.root?d.root : d.values })
```

eventually I can see the tree that I wanted but when I inspect the data, I can see each of the data object under the top level ('root')

```
//from chrome developer console, just take 1 data object as example

Object {root: Array[3], x0: 1730}
root: Array[3]
    0: Object
    children: Array[1]
    depth: 1
    key: "1"
    parent: Object
    values: Array[1]
    x: 187.48768472906406
    x0: 187.48768472906406
    y: 261.3333333333333
    y0: 261.3333333333333
    __proto__: Object
    ...
```

I understood the structure is like

`root -> accessLevel = 0 -> role=admin`

so that **values:Array[1]** is where the child object that has role=admin being stored, but how about the **children:Array[1]**?  It actually means the same as the other since I explicitly assigned the children key is **role**

Now question is: is this just because chrome display the data inspection in this way? or actually the data object has duplicated things stored (values and children arrays in my case) ? if yes, it could be annoying if this is for a huge data source.

I am very sure there must be better ways as well, please advise me, thanks all!

Comment: Yes, you are duplicating things here, although that shouldn't be much of a problem in practice. You can try `.children(function(d) { return d.values; })` if you don't want the duplication.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I still found the data object that has **values** property also has **children**, does that mean the two properties are duplications?

Comment: Hmm, you must be setting `children` somewhere else in your code then. In fact, the code you've posted to set the accessor shouldn't do that either.